# Android notification dots appearing on random apps

Tags: notifications, 8.0-oreo

I'm seeing a pale red notification dot randomly on apps in the launcher, even though I dont have notifications from that app.

Couldn't find much details online. Is it an indication that there is some background network activity from those apps at the moment? Is there a way to enable/disable this?

I have a OnePlus 3 with OxygenOS 5.0.1 (Android 8.0.0)

Here are a few screenshots, taken a few seconds apart.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: No, I have never enabled/used parallel apps. I don't think its about parallel apps (like in the question you mentioned). This dot is exactly like the Oreo notification dot, but pale red in color. And I have not seen it before today.

Comment: I just checked, all app notifications are enabled, in fact by now I have seen the dot shift from one app to the other, and on almost 30% of the apps in the launcher! (I have a few hundred apps). Edited the question to add Facebook image, whose notifications I am actively receiving.

Comment: This is [reported here](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/random-notification-dots.714002/) with a solution

Comment: According [to this](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/some-dots-on-apps-in-app-drawer-are-visible-randomly-cant-figure-out-what-they-are.757973/) you need to update launcher and clear cache. On device forums [reported and closed as bug](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/closed-weird-notification-dots.758973/)

Comment: Its localized to only OnePlus devices I see, a quick restart is solving it for a while. The Oreo update by the folks at OnePlus has been a little buggy, it breaks my network connection every now and then, but gets temporarily fixed after a restart. Anyway, keeping the question open in case someone is looking for what it is! Thanks :)

Comment: Added an answer, will keep it up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, this seems to be a bug and only appearing in OnePlus phones post the latest Oreo 8.0.0 update. It is unclear what they denote though.

Restarting the phone solves the problem temporarily. It will be safe to assume that a fix could come out in the next patch from OnePlus.

As @beeshyams discovered, this has been reported [few](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/random-notification-dots.714002/) [times](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/some-dots-on-apps-in-app-drawer-are-visible-randomly-cant-figure-out-what-they-are.757973/) [on the forums](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/closed-weird-notification-dots.758973/)